# How to fetch data from secondary calendars in google calendars?

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I am writing a code that displays all events of all calendars synced with a particular Gmail account.But I am able to get data from primary calendar only . Can someone help in how to do it for secondary calendars?

Comment: Can anyone please help me in this.. I want this on Android 4.0

Comment: I have done it..... Thanx for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HERE IS THE CODE FOR GETTING ALL EVENTS :

```
Uri l_eventUri; 
l_eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");

    Cursor l_managedCursor = null;  
     l_managedCursor = this.managedQuery(l_eventUri, null,null, null, null);


     l_managedCursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.v("TOTAL NUMBER OF EVENTS :",l_managedCursor.getCount()+"");

 for(int i=0;i<l_managedCursor.getCount();i++){
for(int j=0;j<l_managedCursor.getColumnCount();j++){

    Log.d(l_managedCursor.getColumnName(j)+"===>",""+l_managedCursor.getString(j));
}

l_managedCursor.moveToNext();
```

}

*The most important thing is to sync the gmail calendar in your device In ICS we are given with a choice that whether we want to sync secondary calendars or not. Make sure that secondary calendars are synced in your device.Only then we can get the events from the secondary calendars.
In Android Gingerbread byDefault all the calendars are Synced when we choose accounts&sync whereas in ICS only the selected ones are synced***